# How can I setup an OpenID Connect authentication with Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, openid-connect

here is the thing. I have my app that has separated back-end and front-end into two different project (back-end with Node-JS, and front-end with Vue-JS). I got a home page with a button that should redirect the user to the authentication server to log in.

So i made an "on-click" function in my homePage.vue that will consume a function from my api.

I've read a lot of documentation and seen some examples. But to be honest, during those past weeks, even if I tried, I still do understand nothing about how authentication works.

You can see below the js file i wrote inspired by examples that i found:

**auth.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect');
const app = express();

app.use(
    auth({
        issuerBaseURL: 'myDomainUrl',
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
        clientID: 'myClient_ID',
        secret: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
        idpLogout: true,
            authRequired: false,
    })
);
module.exports = app;
```

There is also the route with the function that I try to implement:

**auth.route.js**

```
module.exports = app => {
    var router = require("express").Router();


    router.get('', location.replace('myDomainUrl'));
    app.use('/api/login', router);
};
```

I don't know if it's important but my back-end runs on the port 4000 and my front-end runs on the port 8080.

If someone can explain me how I can do to make my authentication work and what I have to change, it would be great.

Thanks you in advance, I hope I was clear enough about my problem. If not, do not hesitate to ask me what was not clear.

Comment: What is `myDomainUrl` in your case?

Comment: In my case I put on this field the URL of the authentication server. This URL is the page on which the user is going to write his username/password.

Comment: Have you looked at <https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/express>?

Comment: That's one of the first doc i found yes...